# How to "reset" object's property order? JSON.stringify() preserves them

Tags: javascript, json, properties, stringify

Two identical objects, property order is the only difference:

```
const obj1 = {aaa: 1, bbb: 2, ccc: 3};
const obj2 = {ccc: 3, aaa: 1, bbb: 2};
```

Now if I use JSON.stringify() it will preserve order and produce:

```
{"aaa":1,"bbb":2,"ccc":3}
{"ccc":3,"aaa":1,"bbb":2}
```

Is there a way to "reset" object's property order?
Something more elegant than putting all Object.keys() into an array, then sorting it alphabetically, then creating empty object and adding each property one by one..?

P.S. I know there are better ways to compare two objects but this is not the case.

Comment: Why would you need/want to do this? We never get values from objects by "position" in JS so what does the order matter?

Comment: @gforce301 The order of an object keys **matters** when obtaining _normalized_ `JSON.stringify` results. Guess why [`json-stable-stringify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-stable-stringify) is being used that much.

Comment: @gforce301 However, it is true that depending on an object key's order _should_ be avoided in Javascript, since it is **by design** that Javascript not guaranteeing the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not any way beyond putting the keys into an array. The reason is that JavaScript objects do not have any meaningful order to their keys.

JavaScript objects are essentially hash maps, meaning that there is constant lookup time given any key but the keys themselves do not have a meaningful order. Since the only reason to sort keys in JavaScript would be for readability purposes, there is not a built-in solution that handles this better.